# .NET 7, Linux, GTK#, how to detect waking up from sleep?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-7.0, sleep-mode

After the system goes into sleep mode, it can lose the network connection. I need to know when the PC gets awakened from sleep. How to know that on Linux? The existing answers using `SystemEvents` seem to be Windows-only.